# Use part of text stored in a variable

Tags: xetex, letters, text-manipulation, envlab

Is there a way to take only part of the text from a variable?

My specific use case is with the `envlab` package: I want the `\returnaddress` command to omit the last two lines of the `\fromaddress` variable (from `letter.cls`).

Something like:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{letter}
\usepackage[businessenvelope]{envlab}

\renewcommand{\returnaddress}{
%string processing magic such that the output is
%22 Goat Town\\State of Goats
}

\address{22 Goat Town\\State of Goats\\me@privateemail\\1-900-IDENTITYTHEFT}

\makelabels % this command prints envelope labels on the final page of the document

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Addressee}
This is my letter.
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

I'm working in xelatex.

Comment: Can you add a MWE?

Comment: @egreg MWE added.

Comment: The `xstring` package has macros that are ideally suited for this: `\StrBetween`, `\StrBehind` abd `\StrBefore`.

Comment: @egreg Not sure what the problem would be. There was a missing final `}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We define a `\computereturnaddress` macro that splits off the last two segments of the address and add it at the end of the working of `\address`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{letter}
\usepackage[businessenvelope]{envlab}
\usepackage{xparse,xpatch}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\computereturnaddress}{}
 {
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_marcin_address_seq { \\ } \fromaddress
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_marcin_address_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_marcin_address_seq \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\returnaddress}{}
 {
  \seq_use:Nn \l_marcin_address_seq { \\ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\xapptocmd{\address}{\computereturnaddress}{}{}

\address{22 Goat Town\\State of Goats\\me@privateemail\\1-900-IDENTITYTHEFT}

\makelabels % this command prints envelope labels on the final page of the document

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Addressee}
This is my letter.
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]